# UIButton Transition - run across the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a UIButton attached to the main view (self.view). Its sitting at position (0,0) in Portrait mode.

When user switches his iphone to landscape mode I want the button to appear to run across the screen to position (200,0).

The effect I am looking for is the button to a smooth run back and forth upon changing of the views.

For life of my I couldn't find such a transition in apple docs or google search. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Wouldn't an animation block suit your purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your view controller:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromOrientation

    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
    CGRect buttonFrame = self.button.frame;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(currentOrientation))
        buttonFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    else
        buttonFrame.origin = CGPointMake(200, 0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^ {

        self.button.frame = buttonFrame;
    }];
}
```